# VMware guest can access host but not vice versa

Tags: windows

On my Windows I installed VMware with a guest Centos VM. As a LAMP stack is working on my Windows, I can access the web content from the VM via something like 192.168.11.5.

Later on I run nginx on the VM, as I checked the ip v4 address of my VM is 192.168.222.169. I tried to connect from Windows to this address but without success. What configuration problem is I having here?

(The network adapter I set is NAT. Not sure if relevant here.)

Answer (score 1):

In VMware Workstation 9,
Go to Edit > Virtual Network Editor and select NAT network.
Select the checkbox 'Connect a host virtual network adaptor to this network'

VMware will install a virtual network adaptor (most probably VMnet8) and you will now be able to do both way communication.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no conflict in default routes between your LAN network and VMware guest network if you are using NAT. If using bridged, this isnt a problem because the Host and Guest are on the same network.

I.E:

```
Host:
192.168.0.100
Router:
192.168.0.1
Guest:
192.168.222.169
```

If your Host's network mask is 255.255.0.0, all IP's starting with 192.168 will be sent to your router instead of router internally to the guest. You may not have a problem if you are using a 255.255.255.0 mask, as the IP's 3rd octet's are different.

When using NAT, I strongly recommend sticking to a completely different private IP addressing scheme than the host.

I.e:

```
Host:
192.168.0.100
Guest:
10.0.0.101
```

If you want the server accesible to other computers on the LAN, I recommend using bridged mode instead of NAT. This will allow the guest OS to see the network just as your Host does, giving it an IP in the same subnet, and allowing full communication to other LAN computers and the internet.

If using NAT, you will need to configure rules to allow connections to the guest from the network.